Switching between ubuntu 22.04 and 18.04
I have Ubuntu 22.04 and Ubuntu 18.04 installed on the same computer. If I work on one and then switch to the other, I have to reset the system. I am afraid too many resets may cause problems.
Is there a way to switch between 22.04 and 18.04 without booting the computer?
Zulfi.

No you need to reboot to change OS. If you want to have it another way pick one OS and have the other as a VM. As for too many resets cause problems, no ides what you are thinking it will cause.

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS reached End of Standard Support last year, and is thus off-topic on this site.  You can use ESM/Pro support options (cost maybe involved) if you wish but community support (such as this site) no longer exists, though SE Unix & Linux allow all Ubuntu questions too.  Please see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic or Canonical who provide ESM/Pro services.

If you want to run multiple OS be it Ubuntu or some other OS a reboot is required to bring up the Grub menu and give you the option to choose the other OS.
A solution to not having to reboot each time to change the OS is to pick an OS which the computer will boot each time and have any other OS run as a virtual machine  or VM in that OS.

Hi, Can I do this without harming my data? But VM are  bad stuff. If it does not work can I restore back to my current state?

No having a VM does not harm your data. I do not know where you get your info a VM is not a bad thing. If you do not want a VM just remove it, following the correct method of course.
